# How to format the footer of an HTML email to put elements in a row and not in a column?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to get these two images and two pieces of text (facebook and instagram) to be next to each other on one line. Please look at the picture below. This is not my code, so I do not know where to begin.

It is going to be used in an email, so this is why all of the CSS styles have to be inline.

```html
<tr style='background-color: #1F3466;'>
  <td style='background-color: #1F3466;'>
    <footer style='background-color: #18A5A7;'>
      <h2 style='margin-left: 25px;font-family: sans-serif; color: aliceblue;'>Fique bem informado! </h2>
      <h3 style='margin-left: 25px;font-family: sans-serif; color: aliceblue;'>Acompanhe também o Grupo São Cristóvão Saúde nas redes sociais: </h3>
      <Footer style='display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-content: center;align-items: center;font-family: sans-serif;'>
        <img src='fb_logo.png' style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-left:25px" alt='facebook' /><a style='text-decoration: none;color: aliceblue;' href='https://m.facebook.com/gruposaocristovaosaude/'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook.com/gruposaocristovaosaude</a>
      </Footer>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <footer style='display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-content: center;align-items: center;font-family: sans-serif;'>
        <img src='inst_logo.png' style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-left:25px" alt='instagram' /><a style='text-decoration: none;color: aliceblue;' href='https://instagram.com/saocristovaosaude/'>&nbsp;&nbsp;@saocristovaosaude</a></footer>
    </footer>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: And what do you want it to look like for mobile? It will surely need to stack in mobile, like what flex-wrap:wrap does (but that only works for APple mail, not Gmail or others, https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-flex-wrap/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having the nested tag "Footer" with `display: flex` twice, just move the contents of your second tag into your first one.

Something like this.

```
   <tr style='background-color: #1F3466;'>
    <td style='background-color: #1F3466;'>
        <footer style='background-color: #18A5A7;'>
            <h2 style='margin-left: 25px;font-family: sans-serif; color: aliceblue;'>Fique bem informado! </h2>
            <h3 style='margin-left: 25px;font-family: sans-serif; color: aliceblue;'>Acompanhe também o Grupo São
                Cristóvão Saúde nas redes sociais: </h3>
    
                <Footer
                style='display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-content: center;align-items: center;font-family: sans-serif;'>
                <img src='fb_logo.png' style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-left:25px" alt='facebook'/><a style='text-decoration: none;color: aliceblue;'
                    href='https://m.facebook.com/gruposaocristovaosaude/'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook.com/gruposaocristovaosaude</a>
                <img src='inst_logo.png' style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-left:25px" alt='instagram' /><a style='text-decoration: none;color: aliceblue;'
                    href='https://instagram.com/saocristovaosaude/'>&nbsp;&nbsp;@saocristovaosaude</a>
            </Footer>
        </footer>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Also as a list of changes to make this a lot easier for you:

- Don't nest the `footer` tag, your document should only have one of these.
- Get rid of your inline styles and add them to a css file.

Comment: Note this is for email, so this solution doesn't work across all email environments. Check support levels: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex

Comment: Even footer doesn't have good support in emails.

Answer (score 1):

You could put both elements in a separate div and nest them in the parent div d-flex flex-row. Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: This is for email not web

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are after. Hybrid/spongy method that does not rely on media query for stacking. Your inner two columns ( [Content goes here] ) will have contents of each column. Right now the code when run doesn't show words as the parent td has `font-size:0;`. Be sure to add inline styles for each column.

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;font-size:0;">
            <!--[if (gtemso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
                    [Content goes here]
                </div>
                <!--[if (gtemso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%" valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
                    [Content goes here]
                </div>
                <!--[if (gtemso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```